# I cannot see images in chrome. In firefox they work fine

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm having serious trouble with chrome, I've some ads running through wp-adrotate plugin. These images display fine in firefox but get 0x0 in chrome. What did I do wrong? anything I should have included in html that chrome doesn't like?

## 1, fierfox screenshot, #2, chrome. Notice how banner is gone!

[image]

[image]

Comment: May be you have adblocker in chrome, which removes this plugin from page, so turn it off.

Comment: @Aleksey my god. you are so right! this happened to me second time... damn adblock that blocks even my own ads :D ty! this is an answer.

Comment: Should I write this as the answer below?

Comment: Aleksey: Yes, you definitely should. I'll even upvote it for you.

Comment: @Aleksey please write it as an answer, I will approve it.

Comment: I feel your pain: I've done this exact thing. 15 minutes into troubleshooting why one of the tabs on this page was empty, I realized the whole problem was that it was in the DOM as `<div id="ads">`. Chrome's AdBlock Plus seems more aggressive than Firefox's in a bad way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have adblocker in chrome, which removes this plugin from page, so turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove your cache from your browser then try again.